# Javascript Lightbox Effects not working anymore after jquery .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

Please help me with the following problem. I spent a whole day searching fixes on the net and trying to make it work with no succes.

I have this Menu Link( I click on this link to load the code from foto.php in the #afisare_continut div, found in about.php ):

```
<li onclick="foto()">
   <a data-toggle="tab" href="#foto" id="submenu7">
   <div>
      Foto
   </div></a>
</li>
```

I have this jquery function attached to the above onclick event:

```
function foto() {
                $('div[class^="tab-pane"]').hide();
                 $("#afisare_continut").load("foto.php");
            }
```

Div class "tab-pane" it would be a previous loaded code from different file.
I have this container div in wich the foto.php file loads:

`<div class="tab-content continut_tab container clearfix" id="afisare_continut"> </div>`

This is the foto.php code:

```
<div id="fotoechipa" class="masonry-thumbs col-6" data-big="3" data-lightbox="gallery" style="margin-right: -1px; position: relative; height: 429px;">
      <a href="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/full/1.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-item" style="width: 190px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><img class="image_fade" src="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/4/1.jpg" alt="Gallery Thumb 1" style="opacity: 1;"></a>
       <a href="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/full/2.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-item" style="width: 190px; position: absolute; left: 190px; top: 0px;"><img class="image_fade" src="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/4/2.jpg" alt="Gallery Thumb 2"></a>
       <a href="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/full/3.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-item" style="width: 380px; position: absolute; left: 380px; top: 0px;"><img class="image_fade" src="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/4/3.jpg" alt="Gallery Thumb 3" style="opacity: 1;"></a>
       <a href="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/full/4.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-item" style="width: 190px; position: absolute; left: 760px; top: 0px;"><img class="image_fade" src="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/4/4.jpg" alt="Gallery Thumb 4"></a>
       <a href="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/full/5.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-item" style="width: 190px; position: absolute; left: 950px; top: 0px;"><img class="image_fade" src="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/4/5.jpg" alt="Gallery Thumb 5"></a>
       <a href="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/full/6.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-item" style="width: 190px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 143px;"><img class="image_fade" src="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/4/6.jpg" alt="Gallery Thumb 6" style="opacity: 1;"></a>
       <a href="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/full/7.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-item" style="width: 190px; position: absolute; left: 190px; top: 143px;"><img class="image_fade" src="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/4/7.jpg" alt="Gallery Thumb 7"></a>
       <a href="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/full/9.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-item" style="width: 190px; position: absolute; left: 760px; top: 143px;"><img class="image_fade" src="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/4/9.jpg" alt="Gallery Thumb 9"></a>
       <a href="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/full/10.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-item" style="width: 190px; position: absolute; left: 950px; top: 143px;"><img class="image_fade" src="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/4/10.jpg" alt="Gallery Thumb 10"></a>
       <a href="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/full/11.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-item" style="width: 190px; position: absolute; left: 380px; top: 285px;"><img class="image_fade" src="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/4/11.jpg" alt="Gallery Thumb 14"></a>
       <a href="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/full/12.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-item" style="width: 190px; position: absolute; left: 570px; top: 285px;"><img class="image_fade" src="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/4/12.jpg" alt="Gallery Thumb 12"></a>
       <a href="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/full/8.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-item" style="width: 190px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 286px;"><img class="image_fade" src="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/4/8.jpg" alt="Gallery Thumb 13" style="opacity: 1;"></a>
       <a href="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/full/12-1.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-item" style="width: 190px; position: absolute; left: 190px; top: 286px;"><img class="image_fade" src="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/4/12-1.jpg" alt="Gallery Thumb 15"></a>
       <a href="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/full/6-1.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-item" style="width: 190px; position: absolute; left: 760px; top: 286px;"><img class="image_fade" src="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/4/6-1.jpg" alt="Gallery Thumb 16"></a>
       <a href="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/full/6-2.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-item" style="width: 190px; position: absolute; left: 950px; top: 286px;"><img class="image_fade" src="http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/portfolio/4/6-2.jpg" alt="Gallery Thumb 12-1"></a>
</div>

`
```

You can see on the following link, how the loaded code from foto.php should work. Go to this link and click on an Image and see the LightBox effect working: [click here](http://themes.semicolonweb.com/html/canvas/gallery.php)

Well, the problem is that after I use the Jquery .load() method to bring(.load() ) that Gallery Images code from "foto.php" in the main file "about.php"( in #afisare_continut div), the LighBox effect won't work anymore. When I click on an image it just sends me to link of the full image, not showing me a Lightbox. But, if a insert the Gallery Images code in the main/initial file(about.php) in wich foto.php was loading, the Lightbox effect works. The Lightbox javascript plugin is: `<script src="js/plugins.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and it's included in the header of the main file "about.php". You can find the code of plugins.js: [here](http://pastebin.com/pb13mF8J)

It seems that the Lightbox code from plugins.js won't apply on the Gallery Images code from the foto.php file(loaded with .load() method). It applies only if the Gallery Images code is already in "about.php".

Please help me to make the Javascript Lightbox Plugin work on the foto.php loaded code.

Comment: Show the JavaScript you use to attach light box please

Comment: Here you go: [link] (http://pastebin.com/pb13mF8J)

Comment: It looks like you are using magnific Popup. There is a lot of documentation here: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html about the API. I think your issue is that you need to re-initialise after you add new images. have a look at this method magnificPopup.updateItemHTML(); it might be what you are looking for. Please post any javascript you are using to initialise the lightbox as this will help debug your problem.

Comment: I don't use any javascript initialiser, as if I put `data-lightbox="gallery" ` to the div and `data-lightbox="item` to the <a element, it activates the plugin. I am using the Canvas HTML5 Premium Template and it simplifies the process.

Comment: You will need to add javascript in this case, check out my answer. The reason for this is that the auto-initialization you've been using only works when the page is first loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize the lightbox after doing the load, change your load function to something like this

```
function foto() {
    $('div[class^="tab-pane"]').hide();
    $("#afisare_continut").load("foto.php",
        /* add callback to load to initialize magnificPopup */
        function(){
            /*initialize magnificPopup*/
            $('#fotoechipa').magnificPopup({
                delegate: 'a', 
                type: 'image',
                /*depending on your needs you may have to add the following line*/
                gallery:{enabled:true}
           });
        });
    }
```

The way to initialize the popup method is taken from [here](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#from-a-group-of-elements-with-one-parent)

Comment: I implemented your code and now the foto.php is not loading in about.php anymore.

Comment: @CostelFlorin is it giving any errors in console? probably a small syntax error somewhere.

Comment: I just checked the console and I saw a 404 error because I put the wrong file location for loading. Your code worked like a charm ! Thank you very much !